# JxBrowser - How to react on a HTML-button click in a Kiosk app without mouse-events

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent, kiosk, jxbrowser

I want to use the JxBrowser in my Kiosk-app (based on Swing). Through its nature, no external-mouse and -keyboard are available. But I want to receive an event, if someone is clicking on a (HTML-) button at a specific website.

Originally, I have used the mouse-listener at the browser-view to receive these events. On my Mac (with an external-mouse) I received the mouse-events, but on my terminal (without an external-mouse) I do not receive any mouse-events from the browser-view. I thought that touch-events are handled like mouse-events - but unfortunately this is not the case.

I tried other event-types but without success. I also tried to add a (transparent) JButton to the browser-view. It was displayed full-screen at top of the browser-view, but without transparency.

Are there any other possibilities to receive such an event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you need to follow these steps:

1. Wait until a web page is loaded - listen to browser load events:
   `browser.addLoadListener(new YourLoadAdapter()`
2. Search for all clickable HTML elements on the page (links, buttons, ...), use simple DOM API or more complex XPath expression:
   `List<DOMElement> hyperlinks = document.findElements(By.tagName("a"));`
3. Attach a listener on each of them:
   `element.addEventListener(DOMEventType.OnClick, new YourDOMEventListener());`

I used JxBrowser for a very similar application a few years ago, on that time the JxBrowser was based on Mozilla. And based on that experience I'm not a big fan of embedding external web browser into Java application.  The same behaviour can be implemented as standard Chrome app or extension with less maintenance problems and unexpected behaviour.

Comment: Thank you so much @manicka. It works perfectly and you saved me a lot of time.